# Where can I find a full spanish dictionary in json or csv?

Tags: api, dictionary

Does anyone know where I can download the complete Spanish dictionary in CSV / JSON? Or some free API that you can use?

Comment: I am also looking for this - any luck?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of words [here](https://github.com/lorenbrichter/Words), it's only a ".txt" file but you can open it on Excel and manage as you want, to finally transform into a JSON file with pages like [Excel to JSON](https://beautifytools.com/excel-to-json-converter.php).

How to edit better your ".txt" file: Use a regular expression in editors like Sublime. Find a full word **(\w+)**, replace with **"$1": my values**. See example bellow:

[image]

*NOTE: This is a github link, so it can be deleted. I hope it helps you, otherway sorry if data cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

A list of all available Spanish words can be downloaded here: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/eswiktionary/latest/

Comment: There's multiple sources for a list of words, but OP requests a dictionary with definitions.

Comment: Not exactly, I might of not expressed myself correctly. I needed just the words. Definitions would have been good too, but was looking for just the words!